App Crashes on a particular screen with Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
I am working with BabylonJS in React-Native Android app, and everything was working fine until I added a release build by creating a keystore and other steps that it requires and now it just simply crashes on both debug and release. I don't think it's related to that but here is the logcat from the crash:
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4e6e6f6c79626152 in tid 10293 (mqt_js), pid 10262 (m.myapp.exampleapp)

2024-07-25 11:41:16.836 10064-10064 DEBUG                   pid-10064                            A  pid: 10006, tid: 10038, name: mqt_js  >>> com.myapp.exampleapp <<<
2024-07-25 11:41:16.836 10064-10064 DEBUG                   pid-10064                            A        #00 pc 000000000008b238  /data/app/~~_CDDKjXA8BSE9tIer63cgA==/com.myapp.exampleapp-AlgfkRtqy9iZ_3hM7ewe9g==/base.apk!libhermes.so (offset 0x12fb000) (BuildId: 7f8ff6385b5fe455c03f7b48cdae12ba78b8c714)
2024-07-25 11:41:16.836 10064-10064 DEBUG                   pid-10064                            A        #01 pc 000000000034d87c  /data/app/~~_CDDKjXA8BSE9tIer63cgA==/com.myapp.exampleapp-AlgfkRtqy9iZ_3hM7ewe9g==/base.apk!libBabylonNative.so (offset 0x6e6000) (BabylonNative::Initialize(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, std::__ndk1::function<void (std::__ndk1::function<void ()>)>)+104) (BuildId: b431f252b69276ed8904a3dd383684bd86d07dd1)
2024-07-25 11:41:16.836 10064-10064 DEBUG                   pid-10064                            A        #02 pc 000000000034c5f8  /data/app/~~_CDDKjXA8BSE9tIer63cgA==/com.myapp.exampleapp-AlgfkRtqy9iZ_3hM7ewe9g==/base.apk!libBabylonNative.so (offset 0x6e6000) (Java_com_babylonreactnative_BabylonNativeInterop_00024BabylonNative_initialize+164) (BuildId: b431f252b69276ed8904a3dd383684bd86d07dd1)
2024-07-25 11:41:16.836 10064-10064 DEBUG                   pid-10064                            A        #08 pc 00000000002ee884  /data/app/~~_CDDKjXA8BSE9tIer63cgA==/com.myapp.exampleapp-AlgfkRtqy9iZ_3hM7ewe9g==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.babylonreactnative.BabylonNativeInterop.initialize+0)
2024-07-25 11:41:16.836 10064-10064 DEBUG                   pid-10064                            A        #13 pc 00000000002ee6e8  /data/app/~~_CDDKjXA8BSE9tIer63cgA==/com.myapp.exampleapp-AlgfkRtqy9iZ_3hM7ewe9g==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.babylonreactnative.BabylonModule.lambda$initialize$0+8)
2024-07-25 11:41:16.836 10064-10064 DEBUG                   pid-10064                            A        #15 pc 00000000002ee684  /data/app/~~_CDDKjXA8BSE9tIer63cgA==/com.myapp.exampleapp-AlgfkRtqy9iZ_3hM7ewe9g==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.babylonreactnative.BabylonModule.$r8$lambda$j37y4AgoE66EQfJTB__HdF9vkXU+0)
2024-07-25 11:41:16.836 10064-10064 DEBUG                   pid-10064                            A        #17 pc 00000000002ee61c  /data/app/~~_CDDKjXA8BSE9tIer63cgA==/com.myapp.exampleapp-AlgfkRtqy9iZ_3hM7ewe9g==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.babylonreactnative.BabylonModule$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run+8)
2024-07-25 11:41:16.836 10064-10064 DEBUG                   pid-10064                            A        #20 pc 0000000000363e30  /data/app/~~_CDDKjXA8BSE9tIer63cgA==/com.myapp.exampleapp-AlgfkRtqy9iZ_3hM7ewe9g==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage+0)
2024-07-25 11:41:16.836 10064-10064 DEBUG                   pid-10064                            A        #24 pc 0000000000363fbe  /data/app/~~_CDDKjXA8BSE9tIer63cgA==/com.myapp.exampleapp-AlgfkRtqy9iZ_3hM7ewe9g==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run+74)

I'm using these versions:
   "@babylonjs/core": "^7.16.1",
    "@babylonjs/loaders": "^7.16.1",
    "@babylonjs/react-native": "^1.8.6",
    "@babylonjs/react-native-iosandroid-0-71": "^1.8.6",
    "react-native-permissions": "^4.1.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",

Here is my tsx:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { COLORS } from "../utils/COLORS";

import { useEngine, EngineView } from '@babylonjs/react-native';
import { ArcRotateCamera, Camera, Scene, SceneLoader, Color4, } from "@babylonjs/core";
import '@babylonjs/loaders/glTF';

const BabylonReactNativeTest = () => {

    const engine = useEngine();
    const [scene, setScene] = useState<Scene>();
    const [camera, setCamera] = useState<Camera>();

    const ClientGLTF = "";

    const renderClient = () => {
        SceneLoader.LoadAsync(ClientGLTF, undefined, engine)
            .then(loadedScene => {
                if (loadedScene) {
                    setScene(loadedScene);

                    // logMeshesAndAnimationNames(loadedScene.meshes, loadedScene.animationGroups);

                    // Camera & Light
                    loadedScene.createDefaultCameraOrLight(true, undefined, true);
                    (loadedScene.activeCamera as ArcRotateCamera).alpha += Math.PI;
                    setCamera(loadedScene.activeCamera!);

                    // Scene Bg Color
                    const lightBlueColor = new Color4(
                        208 / 255,
                        236 / 255,
                        255 / 255,
                        1.0,
                    );
                    loadedScene.clearColor = lightBlueColor;
                } else {
                    console.error('Error loading loadedScene.');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading scene: ', error);
            });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (engine) {
            renderClient();
        }
    }, [engine]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <EngineView
                camera={camera}
                displayFrameRate={false} />
        </View>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.PRIMARY_BLUE_BG,
    },
})

export default BabylonReactNativeTest;

How can I find out what is breaking the app? It's just crash if I have const engine = useEngine(); or anything from import { useEngine, EngineView } from '@babylonjs/react-native';
